# How to receive user input for Array to then use for a paint method?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, awt, paint

```
package package13;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class BarChartApplet extends JApplet {


    final int baseX=30;
    final int baseY=100;
    final int width=10;
    final int space=30;

    //int height[]={30,20,40,90};

    int height[]=new int[4];

    System.out.println("Enter 4 heights of the bars");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (int k=0;k<height.length;k++) {
    height[k]=scan.nextInt();
    }

    int upperLeftX;
    int upperLeftY;


    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawLine(5, 100, 200, 100);

        for (int i=0;i<height.length;i++) {

            upperLeftX=baseX+i*(width+space);
            upperLeftY=baseY-height[i];
            g.fillRect(upperLeftX,upperLeftY,width,height[i]);

        }

    }
}}
```

I am trying to get user input for values of an array. I am using the values of these arrays to then use to set a height for the bars in the bar graph that I am creating. The problem that I am having is when I attempt to create a `System.out.print` to ask the user to enter values I get an error because I am not using it under (public static void main), but when I try to add public static void main, I get an error for the paint method.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I get an error for the paint method."*  What error?  Always copy/paste error & exception output.

*"Any help is greatly appreciated."*  As is any question.  Do you have a question? Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: Could you show the main? I am assuming that you are creating an instance of BarChartApplet there and then calling the paint method for that instance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem with learning java. You must declare a `public static void main(String[] args){}` method because that's where the application starts executing. You can think of this method as being separate to your class. It must still be declared inside a class but you can declare the method in any class and do things with it, the difference is that if you declare it in another class you must then execute the program from that class.

In order to use methods from your class in `main` you can do one of two things:

Declare the methods as static. This means that the method is not directly associated with any one object of that class but is just part of the class itself. So if you have a class:

```
public class Apple{
    public void eat(){}
    public static void describe(){}
}
```

then you have to have a specific `new Apple yourApple().eat();` to eat but you can describe any apple by going `Apple.describe();`. In fact this example is a bit fictitious because in real life you can describe any one specific apple as well as a general apple but in this java case you can only describe an average apple, if you go `new Apple yourApple().describe();` it will be equivalent to `Apple.describe()`.

This static way of using methods is hard to expand over large projects because it tries to work around the class format of java, but its a good quick way to make a simple example. The second way that I've kind of already shown is called instantiating and it works by making an Apple inside your main class and calling methods on it:

```
public class Apple{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Apple apple = new Apple();
        Apple.eat();
    }
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("Nom");
    }
}
```

I hope that helped.

Comment: It bothered me so much when I first started

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code into a method.  Methods are the only thing you can execute.  The `main` method is the entry point to any Java program.  It must be static since there cannot exist any instances yet.

This code in particular needs to be wrapped into main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int height[]=new int[4];

    System.out.println("Enter 4 heights of the bars");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (int k=0;k<height.length;k++) {
        height[k]=scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

I also noticed that you never actually call paint.  I am not sure what to suggest here because I have no idea what you are trying to do.  How/why do you expect it to run?

Comment: Well when I replace the attempt to receive user input and make the height array have values that I put in there it works.

Comment: Right, because you can define variables outside of a method.  But you cannot put any other instructions.  (unless you use an init block, but that is rarely the right solution)